# Fetch-api error-handling when posting form-data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a single `ReactJs` form-component (writing in `TypeScript` targeting `ES6`) which I will use for all forms in my web-application.
In order to handle errors when a form is posted, I need to check for errors in case there are any.

This is my `handleSubmit` method:

```
private handleSubmit = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    var theForm = ev.target as HTMLFormElement;

    const formData = new FormData(theForm);

    fetch(theForm.action, { method: theForm.method, body: formData })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok)
                throw Error(response.statusText);

            return response;
        })
        .catch(reason => console.log(reason));
}
```

The action I am currently working on is a simple POST-action (example):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(RequestAccountLoginPost request)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("The application crashed in a way nobody expected. Sorry about that...");
}
```

However, when submitting the form, I always end up with the ASP.net standard error-page.
How I can stop this behavior and stay on the page the form is on showing some errors e.g. `There was an internal server-error. Write an e-mail to help@me.please` which helps the user indentifying that something went wrong?

Later I want to implement some handling in case server-side validation fails (but client-side not) so I can show the user: `Look. This value is wrong. Please fix.`. Therefore I do need to stay on the same page.

I'm new to using fetch-api. Maybe this is not the best choosen option for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the normal submission of the form and handle everything in JS, otherwise your page will post by default the data to your server.

```
private handleSubmit = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    var theForm = ev.target as HTMLFormElement;
    ev.preventDefault()
// ... your code
```

> From MDN: The Event interface's `preventDefault()` method tells the user
>   agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default
>   action should not be taken as it normally would be.

Comment: I totally missed this (as of the method-call was inside the `handleSubmit`) so I don't even thought about the original event. Thanks. Would have taken me ages to find out... ;)